# How to show listview in a sliding menu?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a main activity and sliding menu beneath it I want to add a list items to the sliding menu I think my code is right but the list still not showing in the sliding section:

```
package com.example.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView mainMenu ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu, null,true);
       // setBehindContentView(v);

        // Find the ListView resource.     
        mainMenu = (ListView) v.findViewById( R.id.exampleMenu );


        // Create and populate a List of menu items names.  
        String[] menuText = new String[] { "Top 20", "League"};    
        ArrayList<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();  
        menuList.addAll( Arrays.asList(menuText) );  

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the menu list.  
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, menuList);  

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        mainMenu.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 

        // configure the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);

    }


}
```

I am new to android I just want to know do I miss something here ? because the app is working but the menu is not showing . Should I add something to the code?

Edit: the setMenu as it described in the SlidingMenu.java of the sliding menu lib :

```
/**
     * Set the behind view (menu) content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views
     * to the behind view.
     *
     * @param res the new content
     */
    public void setMenu(int res) {
        setMenu(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(res, null));
    }

    /**
     * Set the behind view (menu) content to the given View.
     *
     * @param view The desired content to display.
     */
    public void setMenu(View v) {
        mViewBehind.setContent(v);
    }

    /**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Sliding menu library , but what I can see from the code is that these two lines are  reason for your issue

```
setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu, null);
```

they create two different views one goes to the actulay layout rendering and one you are creating and taking listview to set data but never added to the activity content.

I hope if you change those two lines some thing like this might work

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu, null);
//set this v to setMenu instead of R.layout.sliding_menu
//your codes......
//
//
//menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
menu.setMenu(v);
```

Comment: I try it but still the same . The listview not showing on the sliding menu but the sliding menu itself shows . so i think it is something happened when I add the listview

Comment: whats does this do `getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);` try commenting oout that try

Comment: Please implement this tutorial first : http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html

Comment: so basically setMenu also does the same as  setBehindContentView, so in your original code you are not creating two , but three instances of the same layout. If you are following  some guide or example , i think ur are mixing different examples. just stick to only one and see how it goes

Comment: I edit my question totally using just one resource but I should use the `setMenu` and the `v=getLayoutInflator` together

Comment: instead of passing layout id like R.id.sliding_menu to setMenu ( which will inflate again and set a new view). pass already inflated view to setMenu something like menu.setMenu(v);

Comment: Thank you very much now it show after I passed it as `v`. I hope you edit your answer so I can choose it as the right answer

Comment: Sorry just remove this line `setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);` because I removed it from the code. Thank you again